# How to add a custom keyboard layout to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, microsoft-klc

I have a new notebook that came with a Swedish keyboard, however since my native language is Brazilian Portuguese, I am missing some letters.

I could buy a new keyboard in Brazil, but since I am missing just 2 letters, I decided that it would be easier if I could create a new keyboard layout that contains the letters that I am missing.

To do this I have created a custom layout using the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx), however I have not been able to add it to the Windows keyboard list. In other words, how can I install/import this keyboard on my computer?

Comment: Did you compile the new layout to a setup file (Project -> Build DLL and Setup Package), and then run the resulting .exe to install the new layout?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I ran the .exe file and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply saving the layout isn't enough, you have to install it. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Go to Project → Build DLL and Setup Package
2. When the process completes, click **Yes** to open the folder where the setup file is located
3. Run the **setup.exe** file you generated to install the new layout
4. Finally, go to Control Panel → Regional Settings to select the new layout

Comment: Any ideas about [this](http://superuser.com/q/929302/282033)?

Comment: also on some Windows systems, `msklc.exe` should have no spaces in its path in order to build properly https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.international/c/dR5Z570hwis/m/ix-aBZjhq4UJ