# Created custom keyboard, installed it, but can't start using it

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm currently on Windows while my MacBook gets repaired. I used Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator to tweak Arabic (101) so that layout matched the layout of Arabic letters on my Macbook.

I installed the keyboard, Arabic (101) - Custom, as per the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/496195/how-to-add-a-custom-keyboard-layout-to-windows-7), but I'm now stuck. When I try and add the keyboard under Preferred Languages in Settings, I can choose one of several Arabic language by country, and when I click on options, I have the ability to 'Add a keyboard', which is where my custom keyboard turns up. If I choose to add Arabic (101) - Custom as a keyboard, and then switch to Arabic, the keyboard is still layed out as per the original Arabic (101). If I remove the original and add my Custom keyboard, the whole language disappears from my Preferred Languages.

Can someone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there were updates pending on my Windows machine, and the custom keyboard now seems to work after a restart. When I removed Arabic (101) and added the Custom, the keyboard layout was applied successfully without the whole language being removed.